# COM: How to retrieve CLSID? Can Prog-Id be used?

Tags: c#, com

if I have a known COM library (the .ocx file itself) is there any way in C# to extract the CLSID info of it? Basically I need the same infos from the file Visual Studio adds to its project file when you add a reference to the file. Can these be retrieved from the ocx file directly or by searching the registry?

Also if i know a prog-id, how can I find the CLSID and the corresponding ocx file?

Thanks for your helping out a COM novice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[LoadTypeLib](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221027.aspx)
[CLSIDFromProgID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688386(VS.85).aspx)